# WordPress/Woocommerce: How to get specific child category by 'id' from parent category ID

Tags: php, woocommerce, categories

I found a nice code(shown below) from this [Website](https://www.themelocation.com/how-to-display-all-the-subcategories-from-a-specific-category-in-woocommerce/).

It works great but I need to get a specific child category by 'id'.
For example, if the output from the code is:

Red
Blue
Green
Yellow

How to get only Green because I need to make another query to use it in

```
     'tax_query'=>array('field'=>'id')
```

Here is the function:

```
    //woocommerce get sub categories from parent id
    function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($parent_cat_ID) {
       $args = array(              
           'hierarchical' => 1,
           'show_option_none' => '',
           'hide_empty' => 0,
           'parent' => $parent_cat_ID,
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
        );
        $subcats = get_categories($args); 
        foreach ($subcats as $sc) {  
               $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );                               
               echo $sc->name.'</br>';                      
        } 
    }
```

Here is the code where I have to get the specific id of the category:

```
     foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        global $product;
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        if ( has_term( 'phone-model', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
            $cat_check = true;

            $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id,'product_cat',array('fields'=>'ids'));
            $cat_id = (int)$term_list[0];

            $funspecificsub = woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($cat_id);

            $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'product', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 

            'tax_query'             => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                    'field'         => 'id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
                    'terms'         => $funspecificsub,
                    'include_children' =>true
                )
            )
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            $i=1;
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            global $product; 
            if($product->is_visible()){
            echo '<li style=">';
            echo '<a id="cover_'.$i.'" class=" '.$product->id.'" >';
            echo '<div class="">'.get_site_url().'/?add-to-cart='.$product->id.'</div>';
            echo '<h5>'.get_the_title().'</h5>';


            echo '<h6>'.wc_price($product->get_price_including_tax(1,$product->get_price())).'</h6>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
            }else{}
            $i++;
            endwhile; 
            wp_reset_query(); 

        }
    }
```

So I guess the main question is how do I get 'Green' category id in variable $funspecificsub above. At the moment its outputting all the Sub categories. I want to be able to select specific Sub Category.

Comment: What do you mean, “how to get green”? You got ”green” already, because your function just output it. Really unclear what you are actually trying to ask here.

Comment: After getting subcategories I need to make another query to select only one category from them. and there was no need to downvote @CBroe

Comment: That still doesn’t explain what your actual problem is. What step are you having trouble with?

Comment: Check I updated the question @CBroe

Comment: _“I want to be able to select specific one”_ – where/when/how?

Comment: I want to be able to select specific Sub Category.

Comment: _Where_ do you want to select it? Do you still want to output the initial list of Red Blue Green Yellow, and then have the user click on one ... or what?

Comment: No mate. I need the id to be in the variable $funspecificsub. please see the code above. The code above comes after the user adds a product in the cart from parent category.

Comment: Yes, I ask questions to try and clarify what you want, resp. where your specific problem is. That you fail to answer those in a way that makes it understandable what you are having trouble with, is not my fault. _“I need the id to be in the variable $funspecificsub”_ – ok, and once again: What is your actual problem with that?